# How to do notification log as like FB?

Tags: c#, notifications, async-await

I need to do notification functionality as like in FB. If someone add a new object into a system, I want to put entries in notification table to all users as like "New object has been added by Tom." message. But it won't affect performance.

**Consider Tom going to add a new object in a system:**

1. Tom add a object details
2. Save object details
3. Now object details will be passed to DB
4. If it successfully saved, have to show the success message to Tom,
   and parallelly have to put notification entries to all user. It
   doesn't affect Tom's response. Because, Tom no need to wait until to
   complete notification entries.

Can you please suggest your ideas to solve this problem?

**Note:** I have tries with asyn operation. But in some cases it won't works. Async works perfectly when I wait until that process complete.

Comment: "_I have tries with asyn operation. But in some cases it won't works_", could you please include the code that is creating the notification asynchronously so that we can check for the problem if any.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve some thing like running background task without blocking your request, you may need to use below in **System.Web.Hosting** which runs your code as background task even after the response is sent and as long as these are still running, IIS doesnt terminate your worker process abruptly:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken =>
{
    // your code here that puts the entry in Notification table
});
```

But if your purpose is to only send Notification across all the users, you can use Signalr (https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: +1 for SignalR suggestion. But to create a notification which in turn is an IO operation (Database), I suppose it's better to use an async operation (**as it's designed specially for IO specific operations**) instead of creating a background worker thread.

Comment: I have mentioned the same **_use an async operation (as it's designed specially for IO specific operations) instead of creating a background worker thread_** i.e. async mostly doesn't create a new thread which is not required in this scenario.

Comment: when we use async/await, it will not block the parent thread but if the parent thread(request) is terminated then all its child async threads will be stopped(i.e., if the response is generated to client). I think, LTAravindh is facing this issue. That means, async operation is not termed as background tasks, these are parallel tasks. In order to make it to background, we have to use QueueBackgroundWorkItem which will work even after the response is generated in the background.